# Using activiti engine to execute newly created process workflows without restarting the server

Tags: spring, deployment, activiti, bpmn

I'm trying to integrate activiti with one of my existing Spring app. The use case is that we would be creating new workflows every now and then, and don't want to restart the application server every time in order to execute the workflow.

I went through the activiti guide, I think i'll be following the following approach:
1) Add jars to my current application using Maven.

2) Create workflows using the activti designer.

3) Execute workflows.

But from what I understand there's no way to execute the newly created workflow without restarting the engine, and since the engine will be in my app. i'll have to restart the app the everytime.
is there something i'm missing that can allow me to do dynamic deployments of the workflows or is there another bpmn tool that could meet this use case?

Could you please let me know if you've a solve for this use-case?

Thank you.

Comment: no, unfortunately you'll have to restart activiti every time you required a new or re-deployment. If your application needs to be up all the time. consider moving activiti engine to another application

Comment: @AbbasKararawala thanks for the response How about JBPM, I'm going through its documentation and seems like dynamic deployments might be possible it. Do you have any information about it?